# Sample razor pages for managing Identity roles, claims, & policies

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I've added the Identity scaffold to my Blazor Server (version 7) app. Works great for registering users. But now I need to set up roles & claims and then apply policies to pages.

Is there a scaffold to add all the pages needed to CRUD all this? Preferably as Blazor (razor) files. But if it's MVC that gets added to the existing Identity MVC files, that'll work too.

And if not, is there a NuGet package or something that has all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer I was hoping for, but posting this to save others the time. I had a conversation with one of the people connected to the Identity team and they said there is nothing like this out there.

So we're on our own. That said, it's pretty fast to create the needed pages.